# NameError: "global name 'ZIP_STORED' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-zipfile

I'm using the zipfile module in python like this:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
```

And I have a method that uses this library like this:

```
def compress(self, filename, data):
    inMemoryOutputFile = StringIO()
    zipFile = ZipFile(inMemoryOutputFile, 'w', ZIP_STORED)
    zipFile.writestr(filename, data)
    zipFile.close()
    inMemoryOutputFile.seek(0)
    return inMemoryOutputFile
```

But, why am I getting this error:

> NameError: "global name 'ZIP_STORED' is not defined"?

Shouldn't `ZIP_STORED` be in the global namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add

```
from zipfile import ZIP_STORED
```

to your imports, or replace your import with

```
from zipfile import *
```

to import all symbols from `zipfile` to the current namespace.